# Set response cookie does not work on ec2 but working on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, ruby-on-rails-5

I set response cookies by this line of code

```
 module Users
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    skip_before_action :verify_signed_out_user # Skip this action from super class

    .....
    def handle_login(response)
      ApplicationRecord.transaction do
        // Verify user 
        // Issues new token
        auth_token = issue_auth_token user

        # Delete current user auth token and create new one
        session.delete(:current_authentication_token)
        session[:current_authentication_token] = auth_token.authentication_token
        cookies[:current_authentication_token] = {:value => auth_token.authentication_token, :expires => 1.month.from_now, :domain => :all}
        redirect_to users_homes_path
      end
    end
 end
```

It worked well on localhost, but the cookie with key `current_authentication_token` is not saved when I deployed my project to ec2.

Comment: You've posted a single line of code. In which file have you added this?

Comment: I added the line of code to an action of SessionController.

Comment: Again, you might wanna post more of the code.  This one line doesn't really give much information.  Should we assume you're using devise? You've given very little info. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post. I only post the line of code because my code works well on localhost but when deployed to prod I got the problem.

Comment: This seems insecure. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I embedded my page onto an iOS application, and the Webview on iOS app always clear session data when restarting the app. So I have to find a way to save the auth token on the client side.

Comment: This breaks the fundamentals of secure login and is clearly a hack approach and likely won't work in production. Please tell me the name of the app so I can be sure to NEVER use it!  Or find a safe approach.

Comment: How about adding a `:httponly => true` to it?

Comment: And we can restrict hacker to retrieve cookie from js?

Comment: Both of the mechanisms (Cookie Based Authentication and Token Based Authentication) have their own pros and cons as mentioned. In the present era of Application Development Frameworks, cons such as XSS and CSRF are taken care by the underlying framework itself and hence I feel it is without a doubt a clear trade-off on which developers and the stakeholders take the decision.